# how does array.fill.call() work in js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

[Mozilla developer](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/fill) includes the following example for the function fill:

```
[].fill.call({ length: 3 }, 4);  // {0: 4, 1: 4, 2: 4, length: 3}
```

I don't understand what do you need the call() for and how it gets to that output.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a glimpse of what `fill` implementation look like (for the sake of explaining):

```
Array.prototype.fill = function(value) {
    for(var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
        this[i] = value;
    }
}
```

Now when we do `fill.call( { length: 3 }, 4 )` we pass the object `{ length: 3 }` as `this` and `4` as `value`. The rest is obvious.

`fill` is an array function. And to work, it should be called on an object that has a valid `length` property. `fill` then loops from `0` to `length - 1` of that object, setting key-value properties on this object, where key is the current index of the loop (ie. `i` from the above pseudo code) and value is the `value` we pass to it.

But using `call`, we can, instead of passing an array, pass in an **array-like** object which is an object that looks like an array (have a valid `length` property). `fill` is tricked into believing that the object we called it on is an array. And does the same thing for it as it would do for a real array.

Answer (score 0):

Let me re-write your code

```
var arr = [1];
arr.fill.call({ length: 3 }, 4); // {0: 4, 1: 4, 2: 4, length: 3}
```

in above code if you don't use `call`, you see it return array with length 1

```
var arr = [1];
arr.fill(4); // {0: 4, length: 1}
```

You see, using `call` function you can execute `fill` function on another array. first argument of `call` define functions scope (in your case, array with length 3), and other parameters will pass to function as its arguments
take a look to [call DOC on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)